# How to extract text till 3rd slash of the url in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to PowerBI and would like to extract the text from relateive URL after 2nd and 3rd slash using DAX.

Example URL: /sites/test/1/answer/detail.aspx
I need to extract it up to /sites/test/

I have tried this but it gives me only first half (/sites/).

```
=LEFT(LogParserOut[SiteURL],FIND("/",LogParserOut[SiteURL],FIND("/",LogParserOut[SiteURL])+1))
```

Comment: It's because your nested FIND functions generates the value 7, which corresponds to the second /. Therefore the LEFT function extracts characters 1-7 ( = /sites/ ) from the original url. 
Maybe you can use power query to split the string into several columns before loading it into Power BI?

Comment: Can you use Power Query or M rather than DAX? You can find instances of '/'  with Text.PositionOfAny(your column, {"/"}, Occurrence.Any) to return a list then read from the 3rd value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what you ask, there is a simple way using PATHITEM()

```
StrippedURL =
    PATHITEM (
        SUBSTITUTE ( LogParserOut[SiteURL] ; "/" ; "|" ; 3 ) ;
        1
    ) & "/"
```

@Aldert I would indeed love to see Regex support some day!

Answer (score 1):

OK, to Power-Bi is not that strong with string manipulation and does not support Regex (yet)

So a bit clumpsy but working

```
StrippedURL = 
var firstBS = SEARCH("/";Table[URL];1;0)
var secBS = SEARCH("/";Table[URL];firstBS + 1;0)
var thirdBS = SEARCH("/";Table[URL];secBS + 1;0)
return IF(firstBS <> 0 && secBS <> 0 && thirdBS <> 0; MID(Table[URL];firstBS;thirdBS + 1 - firstBS))
```